# Finding resource label

Tags: sparql

I'm currently learning SPARQL, and I'm exploring the data from dbpedia. Why does this query work:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT
?label
WHERE {
      dbr:Leipzig rdfs:label ?label.
} LIMIT 20
```

But this does not (i.e. id does not return anything)

```
PREFIX geo: <https://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT
?label ?lat
WHERE {
      dbr:Leipzig rdfs:label ?label.
      dbr:Leipzig geo:lat ?lat.
} LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the protocol of the WGS 84 Geo namespace is `http` and not `https`, i.e. http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#

Comment: Thank you! Such a trivial mistake. Are all namespaces http? Or is there a case of an otology URI with https?

Comment: There is no real guideline, but I guess almost all are still `http`. There was a discussion now how to make dereferencable URIs in Linked Data now more safe bei moving to `https` but this would break the idea of having persistent URIs. Yet, if somebody defines a new vocabulary it's free to use `https` as well but I guess `http` is fine.

Comment: Why wouldn't URIs be persistent if for example wgs 84 switched from `http` to `https`? Is it because it would broke old code that contains the `http` version?

Comment: Yes, URIs won't match with the previous data since equality of URIs is also based on the protocol